# How to assign value to dataframe column based on the name of the column and values between columns in R?

Tags: r

In my example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(main=c(2,6,10), 
                 V1=c(1,3,5), 
                 V2=c(3,5,7),
                 V3=c(5,7,9))
```

I would like to create column 5 that would check between which column values the value in *main* falls in and assign the name of the last column that has a value lower than main to it, so in this example the results would be
Row 1 = **2** (main) is higher than 1 (V1), but lower than 3(V2), so column 5 would be **"V1"**
Row 2 = **6** (main) is higher than 3 (V1) and 5 (V2) but lower than 7(V3), so column 5 would be **"V2"**
Row 3 = **10** (main) is higher than 5 (V1), 7 (V2) and 7 (V3), so column 5 would be **"V3"**

I would also prefer **NOT** to include the column names in the code, as there will be a lot of them in the final dataframe and will be subject to change.

Thanks!

Comment: hello Chrisk, what happens if `main` is lower than all other values?

Comment: Hi Ric Villaba, then it should return NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `pivot_longer`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-main) %>% 
  group_by(main) %>% 
  mutate(Col5 = case_when(main > value & main < lead(value) ~ name,
                       main > max(value) ~ last(name),
                       TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(Col5, .direction = "updown") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

```
   main Col5     V1    V2    V3
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     2 V1        1     3     5
2     6 V2        3     5     7
3    10 V3        5     7     9
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping trought every row with `purrr::pmap_chr`, applying `findInterval` on the value on `main` against every other column, then getting the colname of the associated interval:

```
df$interval = purrr::pmap_chr(df, function(main, ...){
  colnames(df)[findInterval(main, c(...)) + 1]}) #+1 because V1 is the second column
```

Result:

```
  main V1 V2 V3 interval
1    2  1  3  5       V1
2    6  3  5  7       V2
3   10  5  7  9       V3
```

##### Further explanation:

`purrr::pmap` loops trough every row in a dataframe, passing all elements of the row as arguments to a function. The first argument of my function is `main`, which will be filled with the first element of the row (the one in the `main` column). The second argument of my function is `...`, the "dynamic dots" (they are actual code). They are used to pass along every other argument that the function receives (in this case, every other element from the row to form the `vec` argument of `findInterval`).

This method need the `main` column to be the first, and that there aren't any other columns exept the ones used to make the intervale on the data frame. Let me know if that isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo!

However, this might work in the example scenario, but in my problem (where columns have almost random names) this approach would not work.

Also, what did you mean in the place of the "..."?

Comment: @Chrisk I edited my answer, check it out :)

Comment: Thanks Ricardo! This works great on the example, but I had problems getting it to works on the real example that is more chaotic and has numerous columns. Thanks anyway! I sorted it out with TarJae's solution.